# Move a combination of fixed and variable keywords to the end of the string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using opencart and my items have something like (-$100 Retail Tag-) in title among with other keywords,
What I need to do is, search for -$100 Retail Tag- (please note that the dollar amount can be different in any listing and this need to be a considered a variable, it can vary between $5 to $10000) in my sql tables and then move (-$100 Retail Tag) to the end of the title

I have over 4000 items and everyone has a different $amount. so I was thinking of taking everything from -$ to tag and move the whole thing to the end

My table name is oc_product the column is name so it is (oc_product.name)

Here are two examples of the complete title

```
Collectable-Handmade-$100 Retail Tag-Authentic-.925 Sterling Silver-Coral-Turquoise
```

and

```
$263 Retail Tag-New-Handmade-Authentic-Gold-Turquoise
```

Thank you

Comment: If you had a table with one row per tag/product combination (a junction table), then this would be much easier.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, the problem is the title was imported from another marketplace, anything you can think of, to take everything between -$ to tag and move it to the end?

Comment: Do you have anything in mind, I might be able to play with it and work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dollaramount=100;

$query="SELECT oc_product.name from oc_product where oc_product.name like '%$dollaramount Retail Tag-%'";
```

and then run the query

Comment: The problem is I have over 4000 product and every item has a different $ amount, so I can not specify a dollar amount for all of them, we need to take everything from -$ to tag and move the whole thing to the end, any suggestion?

Comment: @Schwann as Gordon said, you better make a column for the dollar amounts and extract dollar amounts of each record by php. by this approach, you should change its value whenever the master field value changes

Comment: There is already a price column which at this moment is not linked to the tile price $value in title, what should I have in my title next to $ sign in order to call the price from a column instead of having it entered manually, the product_id the what is common between the two table (one with price and one with title)?